# What is the proper method to pipe the output of the cut command into a grep command?

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, cut

I am currently learning a little more about using Bash shell on OSX terminal. I am trying to pipe the output of a cut command into a grep command, but the grep command is not giving any output even though I know there are matches. I am using the following command:

```
cut -d'|' -f2 <filename.txt> > <temp.txt> | grep -Ff <temp.txt> <searchfile.txt> > <filematches.txt>
```

I was thinking that this should work, but most of the examples I have seen normally pipe *grep* output into the *cut*. My goal was to cut field 2 from the  file and use that as the pattern to search for in . However, using the command produced no output.

When I generated the temp.txt first with the *cut* command and then ran the *grep* on it manually with no pipe, the *grep* seemed to run fine. I am not sure why this is?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**process substitution**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) here:

```
grep -Ff <(cut -d'|' -f2 filename.txt) searchfile.txt > filematches.txt
```

`<(cut -d'|' -f2 filename.txt)` is feeding cut command's output to `grep` as a file.

Comment: I like that solution because it is a simple one-liner. In my example, the <filename.txt> has 20,000 records and the <searchfile.txt> has about 2.5 million records. I have read a lot of threads here trying to find different ways to optimize grep when processing larger files like this. I had this running for about 4 hours today and it still hasn't finished. I have used the LC_ALL=c, LANG=C options mentioned in previous threads. Are there any optimization methods you would recommend for increasing the speed of grep with larger files?

Comment: If you show some sample data of both files in question then may be I can come up with some way to make it fast.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a *reason* this line doesn't behave as you expect

```
cut -d'|' -f2 <filename.txt> > <temp.txt> | grep -Ff <temp.txt> <searchfile.txt> > <filematches.txt>
```

is that the output of your cut is going to `temp.txt`. You're not sending anything to the pipe.  Now, conveniently pipe also starts a new commend, so it doesn't matter much -- `grep` runs and reads `searchfile.txt`.

But what are you trying to *do*?  Here's what your command line is trying to do:

1. take the second pipe-delimited field from filename.txt
2. write it to a file
3. run grep ...
4. ... using the contents of the file from 2 as a grep search string (which isn't going to do what you think either, as you're effectively asking grep to look for the pattern `match1\nmatch2...`)

You'd be closer with

```
cut ... && grep ...
```

as that runs grep assuming cut completes effectively. Or you could use

```
grep -f `cut ...`
```

which would put the results on the command line. You need to mess with quoting, but you're still going to be looking for a line containing ALL of your match fields from cut.

I'd recommend maybe you mean something like this:

```
for match in `cut ...`
do
    grep -f $match >> filematches.txt
done
```

Comment: thanks for that info. I hadn't thought about using the && option there. Would any of these options have better performance than another? The <searchfile.txt> file I am working with has about 2.5 million records in it and the pattern file <filename.txt> has about 20k rows in it.

Comment: Playing with it a little, I think the && version is probably closest, as long as you're confident that grep gives you the results you want using the -F. But I haven't tried it with 20K rows, which will be an ... interesting test of greps FSA compiler.